# Технологии похожие на Entity Framework

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework

Какие технологии подключения к базе данных похожи на Entity Framework в c#?

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ответы [отсюда](https://qna.habr.com/q/47)

> Пользовался NHibernate, Entity Framwork, Linq2Sql, Gentle.Net. ИМХО
> NHibernate на текущий момент самая гибкая и самая продвинутая ORM.
> Сразу рекомендую использовать ее в связке с FluentNhibernate.
> ENtityFramework постепенно подбирается по возможностям к NHibernate,
> так что если есть желание использовать что-нибудь непосредственно от
> MS используйте его.

Answer (score 1):

[LINQ to DB](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db) (linq2db) - лучшее из того, что придумало на сей момент человечество.

Если страшно вот так сразу отказаться от EF, то можно сперва попробовать [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) - интеграция linq2db в EF Core.